Angular file upload convert base64 to string binary
From file upload I get the data as below:
data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcNCiW1tbW1D...

I want to convert this to a string binary because I need to send file upload data together with other parameters like:
   var arraytosend = [{"id" : 0111,
  "file" : binary data here}]

I tried converting from base 64 to binary but am not able to do so.

"I tried converting from base 64 to binary" what exactly have you tried, and what issues did you have with it? Maybe some error message? Would be helpful to add that to the question.

You can use a function mentioned in this gist for doing this.
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
  // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
  var byteString;
  if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
      byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  else
      byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

  // separate out the mime component
  var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

  // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
  var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
}

